# How to specify x/y axis label values outside chart

Tags: r

I want to add labels to the x and y axis where `geom_segment` lines end at. Something like this:

[image]

The code I'm working with:

```
ggplot(exp, aes(voltage)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = current , colour = "current")) +
  geom_segment(x = 0, 
               xend = 4.44993305,
               y = 0.039496649, yend = max( 
                 0.039496649)) +
  geom_segment(x = 4.44993305, 
               xend = 4.44993305,
               y = 0, yend = max(   
                 0.039496649))+
  geom_text(x = 4.44993305 + 0.1, 
            y = 0.039496649+0.0020, label = "MPP", check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "forestgreen")) +
  annotate(geom = "point", x = 4.44993305, y = 0.039496649, colour = "orange", size = 3)  + 
  labs(colour = "", x = "Voltage(V)", y = "Current(mA)", title = "P-V Curve") + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0.05, 0), limits = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 6))
```

reproducible code:

```
structure(list(current = c(0.04465198144317, 0.04463520273566, 
0.04460114613175, 0.04457135125995, 0.0445214137435, 0.04453720897436, 
0.04449214786291, 0.04451920464635, 0.04460586234927, 0.04455019906163, 
0.04449771717191, 0.04447644948959, 0.04445287585258, 0.04446478188038, 
0.04446309804916, 0.04443653672934, 0.04444691166282, 0.0444468036294, 
0.04446209222078, 0.04440823569894, 0.04440270736814, 0.04439539834857, 
0.04439954087138, 0.04436922073364, 0.04438590630889, 0.0443644374609, 
0.04435379058123, 0.04435301944613, 0.04435969889164, 0.04429738968611, 
0.04429103061557, 0.04427329823375, 0.04427855834365, 0.04435616359115, 
0.04431574419141, 0.04425121843815, 0.04425748437643, 0.04426665976644, 
0.04420702531934, 0.04421706870198, 0.04422586038709, 0.04420934617519, 
0.04419368878007, 0.04420448094606, 0.04418215155602, 0.0441633015871, 
0.04416632652283, 0.04419567808509, 0.0441645719111, 0.04414548352361, 
0.0441205650568, 0.04409914091229, 0.04407843202353, 0.04408247023821, 
0.0440976023674, 0.04407130554318, 0.04406511038542, 0.04406157508492, 
0.04411358013749, 0.04408717527986, 0.04403834789991, 0.04397377744317, 
0.04399513080716, 0.04394119232893, 0.04393403977156, 0.04395672306418, 
0.04391529783607, 0.04388456046581, 0.04384018108249, 0.04377613589168, 
0.04371620714664, 0.04360201209784, 0.04351374134421, 0.04337716847658, 
0.04323555156589, 0.0430811829865, 0.04289939254522, 0.04273791983724, 
0.04255214333534, 0.04230800643563, 0.04205309599638, 0.04180316627026, 
0.04153088480234, 0.04128103330731, 0.04098862782121, 0.0406355522573, 
0.04026722535491, 0.03988171741366, 0.03949664905667, 0.03904519975185, 
0.03858072310686, 0.03809594735503, 0.03754813969135, 0.03698132932186, 
0.03636532649398, 0.03573113679886, 0.03502003848553, 0.03427068144083, 
0.03349439799786, 0.03265217319131, 0.03173480927944, 0.03077974915504, 
0.0297338180244, 0.02861846797168, 0.02742668054998, 0.02613251283765, 
0.02471670508385, 0.02320869639516, 0.02159749343991, 0.01984822377563, 
0.01790586858988, 0.01580262370408, 0.01354998257011, 0.0110809514299, 
0.008333564735949, 0.005422144662589, 0.002235329709947), voltage = c(0.0497902818024, 
0.1001076325774, 0.1500261873007, 0.200014218688, 0.2499825656414, 
0.2999092638493, 0.3499111533165, 0.3998158872128, 0.4498016238213, 
0.5000447034836, 0.5500398874283, 0.6000450849533, 0.6499763131142, 
0.6999563574791, 0.749892115593, 0.7998710870743, 0.8501480221748, 
0.9000863432884, 0.9500870704651, 1.000000834465, 1.0499948263168, 
1.0999064445496, 1.1499096155167, 1.1998677253723, 1.2501357793808, 
1.3001333475113, 1.3500553369522, 1.4000434875488, 1.4499852657318, 
1.4999231100082, 1.549925327301, 1.6001867055893, 1.6501588821411, 
1.7000889778137, 1.7500828504562, 1.800025343895, 1.8499475717545, 
1.899978518486, 1.949893116951, 2.0002207756042, 2.0501630306244, 
2.1001031398773, 2.1501016616821, 2.2000172138214, 2.2499938011169, 
2.299911737442, 2.3502452373505, 2.4001979827881, 2.4501132965088, 
2.5001027584076, 2.5500218868256, 2.5999536514282, 2.6498956680298, 
2.6998517513275, 2.7501895427704, 2.8001124858856, 2.8500940799713, 
2.9000113010406, 2.9500093460083, 2.9999513626099, 3.0498661994934, 
3.1002125740051, 3.1501111984253, 3.2001020908356, 3.2500350475311, 
3.3000183105469, 3.3500154018402, 3.399943113327, 3.4499311447144, 
3.5001940727234, 3.550187587738, 3.6001205444336, 3.6500551700592, 
3.7000305652618, 3.7499585151672, 3.7999482154846, 3.8501899242401, 
3.9001405239105, 3.9500863552094, 4.0000004768372, 4.0499835014343, 
4.0999245643616, 4.1499009132385, 4.1998748779297, 4.2501282691956, 
4.300087928772, 4.3500247001648, 4.3999924659729, 4.449933052063, 
4.4998655319214, 4.5498738288879, 4.6001214981079, 4.6501264572144, 
4.7000713348389, 4.7500491142273, 4.8000221252441, 4.8499178886414, 
4.8999338150024, 4.9498329162598, 5.0001378059387, 5.0500822067261, 
5.1000084877014, 5.1500005722046, 5.1999025344849, 5.2499060630798, 
5.2998147010803, 5.3501005172729, 5.4000744819641, 5.4499711990356, 
5.4999628067017, 5.5498695373535, 5.5998673439026, 5.6497716903687, 
5.6997165679932, 5.7502884864807, 5.8000655174255, 5.8499555587769
), PP = c(0.00222323473909097, 0.00446832447547921, 0.00669133990338782, 
0.0089149039981273, 0.0111295772335824, 0.0133571215574027, 0.0155682987722391, 
0.0177994853036886, 0.020063789316651, 0.0222770910799081, 0.0244755193440537, 
0.0266878749124022, 0.0288933163539832, 0.0311234067610935, 0.0333425266619036, 
0.0355435009395142, 0.0377864540419245, 0.0400059609496442, 0.04224285894479, 
0.0444082727560584, 0.0466226130110058, 0.0488307847519388, 0.0510554589725266, 
0.0532371959582141, 0.0554884095769874, 0.0576796845864956, 0.0598800716882498, 
0.0620961560286796, 0.0643209097851773, 0.0664426785032353, 0.068647790123336, 
0.070845543246237, 0.073066656339177, 0.0754094248194155, 0.0775562239145906, 
0.0796533146869037, 0.0818740257541394, 0.0841057026413645, 0.0861989743910597, 
0.0884438994540186, 0.090670223963168, 0.092844186714439, 0.0950209236818901, 
0.0972506190093721, 0.0994095671210524, 0.101571695684362, 0.103801698561548, 
0.106078377387785, 0.108208204874005, 0.110368245128615, 0.112508406553953, 
0.114655722439755, 0.116803246072698, 0.119016134475474, 0.121276764892071, 
0.123404612920738, 0.125589710242767, 0.127779065687917, 0.130135473691482, 
0.132259381554438, 0.134311068741467, 0.136328057755817, 0.138589554231821, 
0.140616301445618, 0.142787169037195, 0.145057990983433, 0.147116924127234, 
0.149205009137113, 0.151245606106401, 0.153224971374792, 0.155200735994985, 
0.156972499532076, 0.158827556562052, 0.160496849197857, 0.16213152475246, 
0.163706264410516, 0.165170808933627, 0.166683893064858, 0.168084640773841, 
0.169232045916551, 0.170314344969572, 0.171389828259531, 0.172349056768834, 
0.17337517472235, 0.174206925818462, 0.1747364477406, 0.175163424900961, 
0.175479256150164, 0.175757444083009, 0.175698148550336, 0.175537422363473, 
0.17524598641866, 0.174603597797929, 0.173814885869911, 0.172737086901316, 
0.171510247194652, 0.169844311111882, 0.167924070855098, 0.165791673720114, 
0.163265365619927, 0.160263395675946, 0.156976981940024, 0.153129179839487, 
0.148813244139014, 0.143987496509493, 0.138497475713147, 0.132236856654388, 
0.125328689163156, 0.11770571721887, 0.109164492545057, 0.0993752346268299, 
0.0884925964284587, 0.0765543079295968, 0.063158282454129, 0.0479204013524691, 
0.0314487942879752, 0.0130765794624036)), row.names = c(NA, -117L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a package specifically for this. `lemon`

```
library(lemon)

ggplot(exp, aes(voltage)) +
  ... +
  annotate_x_axis('IM', x = 4.44993305, side = 'bottom', print_value = FALSE) +
  annotate_y_axis('M', y = 0.039496649, side='left', print_value = FALSE)
```

(where the `...` is placeholder for the rest of your ggplot-commands)

[image]

Comment: Can this make the font bold?

Comment: The additional arguments didn't work as expected. But you can use mathplot... `annotate_y_axis('bold(M)', y = 0.039496649, side='left', print_value = FALSE, parsed=TRUE)`